# Initialize object array with constructor parameter

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, constructor

Lets say I have 2 classes:

```
public class Carinfo {

private String Car;
private Carinfo [] value; 

Carinfo (String someCar, int carValue) {

this.car = someCar;
//At this point I want the "int carValue" to initialize private Carinfo [] value
}
```

The second class creates car objects, for this example I'll do it with an array

```
public class Generatecar {

Carinfo[] mycars = new Carinfo[1];

public Generatecar {

mycars[0] = new Carinfo("Lada", 9000);

}
```

What I want is to insert the carValue into the private Carinfo [] value; array. How do I initialize the array within the Carinfo constructor?

If I said something that is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: First think, how would you do it outside the constructor? And you are missing brackets around your constructor.

Comment: So should all the elements of the array have same value (9000)?

Comment: And why would you declare an array in `GenerateCar` class, if you are fixing it's size to `1`. Why not just have plain `Carinfo` reference?

Comment: The array of `Carinfo`s inside itself doesn't make sense, IMO.

Comment: Why does a `Carinfo` contain an array of `Carinfo`s? What does this array represent and how will it be populated (without infinite recursions)? Perhaps you should elaborate on what these classes should represent and what you're trying to accomplish, rather than just posting code without any context.

Comment: Any reason why CarInfo can't be a List instead of an array (List<CarInfo> myCars)? Would be easier to work with IMO...also, it's a bit confusing to have a private Carinfo field in your Carinfo class - you should only need that field in Generatecar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try create `Contructor` like this:

```
Carinfo (String someCar, int carValue) {
   this.car = someCar;
   this.value = new Carinfo[carValue];     
}
```

Comment: This one sorted it, I was able to verify that the information I needed was in the correct arrays. Meaning I can continue on the homework

Answer (score 0):

You can set an array variable the same way you set any other variable:

```
mycars = new Carinfo[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the value array in the constructor, the usual way:

```
public Carinfo(String someCar, int carValue) {
    this.car = someCar;
    value = new Carinfo[1];
}
```

But you will run into a problem when you try to put an int in your array of Carinfos.
I don't know what other values you plan to put in that array, but you should consider changing its type to int (if that is the only thing you are going to put in it).

Answer (score 0):

value = new Carinfo[carValue];